# How to understand these two soft constraints in the tsp problem?

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

I understand that the soft constraint in the tsp problem is to find the shortest total distance, but I see that the two drools constraints in the example seem to express the distance of each segment and the distance from the last visited city to the starting point? It seems that the distance is not calculated. And, can you explain these two constraints in detail? I'm a beginner, and I don't understand a little bit.

```
rule "distanceToPreviousStandstill"
    when
        $visit : Visit(previousStandstill != null, $distanceFromPreviousStandstill : distanceFromPreviousStandstill)
    then
        scoreHolder.addConstraintMatch(kcontext, - $distanceFromPreviousStandstill);
end

rule "distanceFromLastVisitToDomicile"
    when
        $visit : Visit(previousStandstill != null)
        not Visit(previousStandstill == $visit)
        $domicile : Domicile()
    then
        scoreHolder.addConstraintMatch(kcontext, - $visit.getDistanceTo($domicile));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In DRL (unlike in Java), calling `Visit(..., $distanceFromPreviousStandstill : distanceFromPreviousStandstill)` means its calling the `getDistanceFromPreviousStandstill()` getter:

```
public class Visit extends AbstractPersistable implements Standstill {
    ...
    public long getDistanceFromPreviousStandstill() {
        if (previousStandstill == null) {
            return 0L;
        }
        return getDistanceFrom(previousStandstill);
    }
}
```

If you prefer Java over DRL, take a look at the ConstraintProvider alternative implementation, which is written in Java, uses incremental score calculation too (= can scale), is equally fast (8.3.0+), easier to debug and has code highlighting and code completion in any Java IDE:

```
public final class TspConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[] {
                distanceToPreviousStandstill(constraintFactory),
                distanceFromLastVisitToDomicile(constraintFactory)
        };
    }

    private Constraint distanceToPreviousStandstill(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.from(Visit.class)
                .penalizeLong("Distance to previous standstill",
                        SimpleLongScore.ONE,
                        Visit::getDistanceFromPreviousStandstill);
    }

    private Constraint distanceFromLastVisitToDomicile(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.from(Visit.class)
                .ifNotExists(Visit.class, Joiners.equal(visit -> visit, Visit::getPreviousStandstill))
                .join(Domicile.class)
                .penalizeLong("Distance from last visit to domicile",
                        SimpleLongScore.ONE,
                        Visit::getDistanceTo);
    }

}
```